# jQueryUI Dialog in Dialog input not clickable

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog, tinymce

i've got a tinyMCE in my jQueryUI dialog. If i click on "create link" in my tinyMCE a new dialog opens where i can put in the link.
But when i click the inputs in that dialog the input on the dialog BEHIND gets focussed and i can't put in text in the dialog on top.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Imgur]

Even with z-index i'm not able to make the input (URL) focussable so i can't put in text.

Anyone knows the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this is a know bug for tinyMCE / jQueryUi combination.

There a two solutions though:

```
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
    if ($(event.target).closest(".mce-window").length) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

That worked for me!

But there's another solutions you can try:

```
jQuery(function ($) {      
  $.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
    _allowInteraction: function(event) {
        return !!$(event.target).closest(".mce-container").length || this._super( event );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you - was driving me nuts! First example also worked for me